# Error during file loading in cassandra: No records inserted in 90 seconds, aborting

Tags: cassandra, cql

I got a strange error while trying to load csv into cassandra table(can be seen below). I tried changing the parameters of COPY, such as CHUNKSIZE (30-100) and NUMPROCESSES (2-4), but it only changed the row where the load freezes (it can freeze at 49907, 49897, etc). I do not understand why so, the file is OK [link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nz1-lIhVIujKlady-MrSVl_nQMt4UQoK/view?usp=sharing) (50000 rows).

**Error log:**

[image: Error code]

**My code:**

```
create keyspace hw1 with replication = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};

CREATE TABLE hw1.product_reviews
(
    product_id      text,
    review_id       text,
    review_headline text,
    review_body     text,
    review_date     date,
    star_rating     int,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, review_id)
);

COPY hw1.product_reviews (product_id, review_id, review_headline, review_body, review_date, star_rating) from 'product_reviews.csv' with DELIMITER='\t' AND HEADER=TRUE;
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and cqlsh 5.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to look what happens server side - there should be some errors in `system.log`, etc.

But I want to say that COPY command is usually used for loading of not so big amounts of data. For loading bigger amounts of data, [DSBulk from DataStax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) could be better - it works with Cassandra too.  And here is the [series of the blog posts](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2019/03/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading) on use of DSBulk for data loading & unloading.  In the simplest case, when you have header in the file, and column names are matching header names, the usage could be as simple as:

```
dsbulk load -k hw1 -t product_reviews -url filename.csv
```